# Time taken to receive device token from Apple APNS

Tags: iphone, push, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I knew that Apple doesn't guarantee for Push Notifications but i have doubt  whether it will even delay in sending the device token to `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`  once after the device is registered for APNS.

Is there any time delay from Apple APNS Server to send the device token once device got registered with the Apple APNS?

Thanks in Advance.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, There will be some time delay, This delay would be in seconds, and it depends on the network connection.